# Python rstrip() works strange

Tags: python, string

I faced problem which is an extremely strange for me.

```py
str.rstrip([chars])
```

works really strange manner for me, in one example. (Or maybe I missed some important documentation part).

```
>>> 'car_id__isnull'.rstrip('__isnull')
>>> 'car_id' # works fine
```

```
>>> 'last_success__isnull'.rstrip('__isnull')
>>> 'last_succe' # I do not  understand why this happened ?
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because you have misunderstood what `rstrip` does.  It strips all occurrences of **any of the given characters** from the right of the string.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) is fabulous at describing these sorts of things.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how rstrip works:

1. Expects a string (more like a character sets) in the paranthesis
2. If no value is given, it will remove whitespaces from the right of the string i.e. `'Tons of whitespace on the right     '.rstrip()`

   'Tones of whitespace on the right'
3. If a value is given, then it removes **every occurence** of each and every **character** from the **right** of the given string, i.e. in your first example

   'car_id__isnull'.rstrip('__isnull')

It basically says "Ok, so the characters that i'm supposed to remove from the right are "_, i, s, n, u, l", so it does just that. And since the "car_id" ends with a "d" (not included in the parathesis of rstrip, it just ends there.

But in the second example,

```
'last_success__isnull'.rstrip('__isnull')
```

Since this time, it is supposed to remove the characters as "_, i, s, n, u, l", and of course it removes "__isnull" because it's included in the rstrip, but it it also removes the "ss" at the end of "last_success" as it is ending with the character "s" which is included in the *to be removed* characters list of rstrip.

I do hope this answer helps someone.